# Extract Table data within div using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I have tried all ways to get the table data of a div tag but not successful. When I do a view source I am able to see the values of the table. But when I run to extract the values the table is not even recognized. The table is within this div tag.

```
<div xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
```

Methods tried by me.

```
Element table = doc.select("table").first();
Elements rows = table.select("tr");
for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) { 
    Element row = rows.get(i);
    Elements tds = row.select("td");
    System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + ":" + tds.get(1).text());
}
```

I have tried getting the table by class, tag etc. Is it anything to do with the div tag?

Comment: Are you sure it's the first table in the document? When you download the page using a command-line tool (e.g. curl, wget), rather than a browser, is the table there?

Comment: Its the first table. But I am not able to view that when i download using wget. Why is that. I am able to view that when I do a view source. Is there any way to pull data of this table?

Comment: It may be that the table is only sent with a certain user agent (try sending the same user agent as a browser when using wget), and it may be that the table is only sent when a certain cookie is sent, or when the user is logged in to the site. In that case you'll need to send the required cookie.

Comment: I am trying to pull out the table in this page. There is no login needed for this page. http://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/volume-open-interest/agriculture-commodities-volume.html

Comment: The data is not in the page. It's filled in by Javascript. I don't know why you said you can see the table in view source. Perhaps you confuse "view source" (which shows real source downloaded by browser) with "Inspector" or Firebug view, which shows you current document including additions made by Javascript. The data is not in the page. You won't be able to get it with JSoup.

Comment: Is there any way I can pull out the value other than Jsoup? or in any other language?

Comment: There is a [link](http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20150625&assetClassId=2&reportType=P) there to download an Excel file. You can get that and analyze it with Apache POI.

Comment: You can do this in almost any language. There are two solutions, use something like "phantomjs" to get the "real" page (with javascript interpreted) or use this [URL](http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/md/voi/voi_asset_class_final.xsl&url=/da/VOI/V2/Totals/TradeDate/20150625/AssetClassId/2/ReportType/P?excluded=CEE,CEU,KCB&hidelinks=false&html)

Comment: Thanks.. I need to check on phantomjs.. But with the other url I am able to extract values. Just need to format it now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by [Duffydake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104934/duffydake):

> You can do this in almost any language. There are two solutions, use something like "phantomjs" to get the "real" page (with javascript interpreted) or use this [URL](http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/md/voi/voi_asset_class_final.xsl&url=/da/VOI/V2/Totals/TradeDate/20150625/AssetClassId/2/ReportType/P?excluded=CEE,CEU,KCB&hidelinks=false&html).

and OP replied:

> Thanks.. I need to check on phantomjs.. But with the other url I am able to extract values. Just need to format it now.